# Multiple Connection String

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net, sqlconnection

I am not sure if this is feasible in ADO.NET, but i still want to run by you gurus.

I have a following sql query:

```
select a.name, b.id 
from datasource1_table a, datasource2_table b
where a.id=b.id
```

1) datasource1_table - SQL Server "SQLServer1" connection

2) datasource2_table - SQL Server "SQLServer2" connection

So i have connection string that has login for both the server. I would like execute the above sql in one shot.

Is it possible?

Let me know if you need more information or clarification.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are the tables in databases on the same database server? Or are they on completely different servers? If they are on different servers, you'll find this very difficult to do without selecting data from both databases separately, and joining in memory via DataTables, for example.

Comment: server are on different location and can be of any dbtype - oracle, sql server or mysql

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly.  You can only associate one SqlConnection with a SqlCommand.  What you can do is is create a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) on SQLServer1 that points to SQLServer2.  Then you can reference it like so:

```
select a.name, b.id 
from datasource1_table a, myLinkedServer.myDb.dbo.datasource2_table b
where a.id=b.id
```

On a side note I would change your current syntax to use actual joins.

If linked servers are not an option you will probably have to execute two queries and process the results.

Comment: Yes, indeed, although linked/remote servers can be more complex to maintain (but not unduly so). I've worked in many places where the DBA's will not set them up.

Comment: Thanks Abe. Linked Server is not an option. Also connection can be from any db type - mysql, sql server or oracle.

Comment: Without linked servers I think you will need to execute two separate queries and then process the results.

Comment: Yeah. That's what i figured. Just wanted to take stackoverflow's input.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you cannot use a Linked Server, you may wish to investigate the [DataRelation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarelation.aspx) class

In your example, perform two SELECT's:

```
DataSet domain = new DataSet();

DataTable dataFromA = null;
DataTable dataFromB = null;

using(SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection("FirstConnectionString"))
{
  DataTable dataFromA = //result from SELECT id, name FROM TableA
}


using(SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection("SecondConnectionString"))
{
  DataTable dataFromB = //result from SELECT id, name FROM TableB
}

domain.Tables.Add(dataFromA);
domain.Tables.Add(dataFromB);
```

I have paraphrased the process here.

Once you have both data tables in memory, you can create a DataRelation between them:

```
DataRelation idRelationship = new DataRelation("ABLink", dataFromA.Columns["Id"], dataFromB.Columns["Id"]);
```

You can then explot this [relationship](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.relations.aspx) anyway you wish:

```
foreach(DataRow aRow in dataFromA.Rows)
{
  //matching B Rows:
  DataRow[] bRows = aRow.GetChildRows(idRelationship);
}
```

It's effectively an in-memory index between the two tables.

Comment: dash - Thanks for the sample.

Comment: @MuraliBala I already do exactly the same thing because we aren't allowed to use Linked Servers. Only thing to be aware of is that with large tables, memory will be an issue. In that instance, it's possible to use two DataReaders, one looping through the table on the connection to the first server, and one looping through the table on the connection to the second server.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one server as a linked server to the other one with sp_linkedserver. Then, use the plain ado.net connection and queries:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (LinkedServerName,'SELECT * FROM myDatabase.Customer')
```

Don't you?

Comment: or use Nhibernate with two connections. See the article http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/10/mapping-entities-to-multiple-databases.html for detals

Comment: Sounds good. But my process can connect to multiple datasource in different servers. "NHibernate to do joins across databases so long as they are on the same server"

Answer (score 0):

I was in a same situation as you are now. DBA's did not allow me to use link servers.

So as a solution I implemented WCF service that connects to two different database servers and get record set in to the memory. After data from two databases are in the memory we can play with it.

Please note that you have to take into the consideration how much data we are dealing with as we are grabbing all in to the memory. In order to minimize the data we can retrieve only required data(i.e. avoid using select * from table)